# What will happen if I set `center` and `bounds` at the same time in Angular-google-maps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

For `ui-gmap-google-map`, it seems that `center` attributes conflicts with `bounds` attributes sometimes, but [its document](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) doesn't say which has higher priority if I set both..

Consider the following situation, which I want to change the display area of google map 3 times:

First time changes `center`, second time changes `bounds` and the third time changes `center` again.. Does anyone have ideas about how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you know what to do in order, why not just do them linearly? wait for the centering to finish, then perform change bounds... wait for that to finish and then perform change center again? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As those events are async that are no priorities, center will center the map on the coords you specify , bounds will get all makers, polylines, infos ... and make them fit on the map display

If you want to execute those in order, try using $timeout